# Novel about a cult who survived the destruction of the planet earth by living on a large fragment of it

Tags: story-identification, novel

A number of years ago I saw a hard cover book, red in colour, with golden coloured line drawings covering the front and back. I can't remember the title, but I do remember some of the blurb on the back.

The story revolves around the main character who lives in a cult which I think their parent was in charge of. The main character thought the father was crazy, up until the point the earth was destroyed, and everyone in the cult managed to survive because they were settled on a large chunk of the earth which managed to stay intact after the rest of the earth fragmented for some reason.

I saw this book in Waterstones, UK, about 10+ years ago at least, so it's at least that old. It might have been aimed at young adults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Splinter](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?221321) by [Adam Roberts](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?6729). The protagonist was named Hector, and he was a newcomer to his father's cult.

Two other plot details that I remember:

- The members of the cult regularly took some kind of medication in the form of white pills, but the protagonist's father never disclosed what the medication was.
- Towards the end of the novel, the protagonist encounters aliens composed of vines assembled into humanoid shapes.

The novel was inspired by [Off On A Comet](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1168107) by [Jules Verne](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?159).